# Nexus Repo gives 503 with Maven but not with browser

Tags: maven, nexus

I just created a Nexus repo on a remote server. If I go to a browser on my local computer I see the pom file just fine. However, when I try mvn clean compile I see...

```
http://server:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/com/class/module/1.0.0/module-1.0.0.pom. Return code is: 503, ReasonPhrase:Service Unavailable. ->
```

I know 503 means it can't get the service, but that throws me because I see it fine in the browser.

I have the proxy configured in my settings.xml, and if I remove the referance to the third party dependency I get the central deps fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the settings.xml file...

Comment: Sounds like an issue w/ the proxy you have configured.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Problem was related to the proxy...

When I configured the proxy in my Settings.xml it worked great for external sites, however, it screwed up internal sites (like my nexus repo). So I removed the proxy from my settings.xml, added it to my nexus server, and then mirrored the central repo to my nexus version of central repo.

Now everything works as expected...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your proxy settings. The current settings will cause all requests to localhost to go through the proxy which will not be able to connect with localhost and hence returns a 503.

To solve this issue add the following to the proxy settings in the settings.xml file:

```
<nonproxyhosts>localhost</nonproxyhosts>
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this happens when I don't have proxies configured. If I add a broken proxy configuration that excludes everything I really access it works.

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>broken.com</host>
        <port>3128</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>mymaven|myotherrepo:8080|foo|baa</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Presumably maven is taking default proxy configuration from somewhere, but I have not found out where.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem for ages; tried both answers to this question and also tried everything else I could find on the interwebs but to no avail.

Then I changed the URLs in the `distributionManagement` section of the pom.xml. I used my PCs name instead of "localhost".

As in: mypcname:8081/blahblah instead of localhost:8081/blahblah

And it started to work miraculously.

Answer (score 0):

yes, in my situation, it was proxy problem. if you use gradle, you can set the gradle.properties file with systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=192.168.* ,when target ip is that. Can workaround it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to enable your repository being online. In your nexus repository settings on your server there is an "online" checkbox.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).