# Nexus repo not accessible through proxy in maven settings

Tags: maven, proxy

I have a maven project.
when I build using cmd prompt- It downloads the maven repos, only when the proxy is configured in settings.xml file.
But this proxy is blocking the nexus repos. I do have two nexus repos required for this project. and I get build error -- return code:503 reason phrase: service unavailable for nexus repo contents

If I follow the stack overflow answer [Nexus Repo gives 503 with Maven but not with browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237785/nexus-repo-gives-503-with-maven-but-not-with-browser)

and added proxy to nexus instance and mirrored the nexus in my settings file. Still maven repo works and nexus repos or not accessible.

[my settings.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sra21.png)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have two nexus repos which you need you should configure that in your nexus...in the public group...to handle that...not in Maven settings.xml locally.

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks. I did checked and whatever is available in my nexus public group those artifacts are getting downloaded. And how can I handle    my hosted repository to be part of this public group.

Comment: I resolved this.So I found, accessing maven through proxy?If yes, then internal nexus repos will not work. In that case, Add the proxy to nexus repo. 1. Nexus->Administration->server->enable default http proxy settings->provide the proxy configurations below.                           
Even after adding this, I got 503 service unavailable.                                     
2. Then by adding the repo I created[xyz] to public repositories. Nexus->Repositories->Public Repositories->configuration->From available repo-> Move the xyz to Ordered Group Repositories. Now everything worked perfect.