# Jenkins Deploy to Nexus Unreachable

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

If I do a `mvn deploy` locally on command line my artifact is uploaded to nexus repo.
However job fails on jenkins. I have configured proxy on jenkins.

```
Return code is: 503 , ReasonPhrase:Service Unavailable.
```

Any thing else I can check?

Comment: have you check this question ?
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237785/nexus-repo-gives-503-with-maven-but-not-with-browser)

Comment: Yes, it works fine locally, just not on jenkins even though I have configured proxy (it seems)

Comment: Your nexus server is in the same network as your Jenkins machine? or is behind VPC\Production firewalls\etc.? are you using the same Nexus configuration files in both cases? any chance on the slave the nexus information is configured differently? can you please provide more details?